# AngularJS using WebStorm: values not visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to WebStorm and AngularJS. Can anyone please help me why I am not able to bind data. I am trying to print the value of str. But it always print {{ str }}.

Below is the code.

```
index.html
<body ng-app="invoiceApp">

<div class="main" ng-controller="InvoiceController">

<div  class="container" >
      <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->

      <p>{{ str}}</p>
</div></div></body>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('invoiceApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'invoiceApp.services',
  'invoiceApp.controllers',
  'invoiceApp.filters',
  'invoiceApp.directives'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    //$routeProvider.when('/view1',{templateUrl: '..//partials/partial.html', controller: 'InvoiceController'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

controllers.js

```
 angular.module('invoiceApp.controllers', []).
controller('InvoiceController',['$scope',function($scope){

    function getDatetime() {
        return (new Date).toLocaleDateString();
    }
       //  $scope.date=getDatetime();
         $scope.str='tom';
         $scope.clientData={
    invoiceId: 1253,
    //date1: getDatetime(),
    vat: 15,
    discount: 5,
    customer: {name: 'xyz', company: 'abc', address1: 'airport road', address2: ''},
    company: {name: 'metro', company: 'www.metro.com'},
    orders: [{
        item: 'Hardware', quantity: 32, details: 'hardware purchase', perUnitPrice: 75
    }]
};
```

Comment: Did you load all the JS code in HTML (including angular.js)?

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? Failing that, could you paste an example of it not working in JSFiddle/plunkr etc?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in programming, you need to indent your code. It will help you to develop, and it will be easier for us to help you.

I'm sure you forget to put an "}" at the end of your Controller.

Then, this is the whole .html file ? Because if it's not, you have missing to include the angular.js and your app.js which are needed.

To conclude, give us your log console to see what error is this, or we could not help you.